# Is there a tool that can help convert/transpile/transform a Vue multi-component project in a single Vue file?

Tags: vue.js

The client will only accept a single *.vue file as deliverable, but I'd like to build the app as a multi-component Vue project. I read about SFCs and I don't know that much about Webpack and all that but they seem to be building a distributable in the form of a .js file. 
The final single .vue file should basically inline all other components. My googling attempts have not been very fruitful so far, so maybe a hint or an answer or even a "It's not possible" would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is your "deliverable"? Is it only a file, or a whole web app?

Comment: I think the main question is: WHY?

Comment: @Nino Filiu Well, it's a file that contains a web app. We're forced to write the entire app in a single vue file.

Comment: @BroiStase unfortunately, we do not have much control over the way our delivery is accepted :(

Comment: How about a single .js file that exports the vue app component?

Comment: We could try I guess. Could you provide a link/example ?